# How to bind input value in emblem.js

Tags: emblem.js

I have a `filter` attribute in my controller which I want to bind to the corresponding DOM element.

So far, I am able to display `filter` value, doing:

```
%input type="text" value=filter
```

But what I want is to reflect input changes back to `filter`, with a bidirectional binding...

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view Ember.TextField valueBinding="filter"`

Comment: or just `Ember.TextField valueBinding="filter"`. line-starting capitalization invokes `view` by default

Answer (score 7):

`= input valueBinding="filter"`

is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`= input value=filter`

or even with a sub property :

`=input value=object.property`

both works.